Over $(0,10)$ the function $[\sin x] + [\sin 2x]$ is discontinuous at how many points?

Over $(0,10)$ the function $[\sin x] + [\sin 2x]$ is discontinuous at how many points? [] is the greatest integer function, aka the floor function.

This is a question for an only MCQ exam, so I tried to avoid the algebraic approaches to solving this problem, thinking it would take too long.
I first graphed sin x {RED} and sin 2x {GREEN} over the x values [0,10], which is approximately between [0,3$\pi$] (9.42..). Greatest integer function of sin($\theta$) is always going to give either -1,0,1, so I looked at all points where the graphs either touch -1,0,1 or intersect each other. Based on that, I managed to find 8 points of discontinuity, but the answer key shows 9.
For example, my first point was $\pi$/4 (0.78ish), here [sin(2x)] would give me 1, but at that same point [sin x] would give me [0.707]=0, hence the discontinuity.
But this logic did not help me find all the points. Kindly let me know if I made an error or if you know a more intuitive method to solve it that doesn't take too long.

Note: I have seen the previously posted question on this site, but its too lengthy for my purposes, I would prefer if this question could be solved graphically.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

You say that you've looked at the points where the two graphs intersect, but none of those are marked on your image - I also fail to see why they would be interesting. But the real answer is that you've missed a point where $\sin 2x=-1$.

Just count the points were $\sin x$, $\sin 2x$ goes from pos to neg to $+1$ ( but not $-1$:  $[-0.999] =-1 = [-1]$ whereas $[0.9999]=0; [1]=1$.  $\sin ax=0$ happens predicably may times as does $\sin ax = 1$.

@Henriksupportsthecommunity I did check the points where the graphs intersect, but the floor function never gave 2 distinct points for them, so I hadn't gotten a discontinuity point at them. And I believe I marked every point where sin2x=−1.

You haven't marked $\frac{7\pi}{4}$, but I failed in realising how $\lfloor x\rfloor$ behaves for negative numbers, so the point you haven't marked isn't actually a point of discontinuity. The problem occurs when one of the summands are $0$, most of the zeroes of $\sin 2x$ happen to coincide with one of extrema of $\sin x$, but there is one that you've missed and that actually causes a point of discontinuity.

The present answers already say everything what can be said, here is one more, it gives only the graphical support as a supplement.
First of all, some observations. The sine takes values between $-1$ and $1$ inclusively. So $x\to [\sin(x)]$ takes only three values, $1,-1,0$. The value $1$ is taken in isolated points. Jumps occur only at multiples of $\pi/2$. The function $x\to [\sin(2x)]$ takes also only the three values, $1,-1,0$, jumps are at multiples of $\pi/4$. So let us compute and plot the values at such multiples of $\pi/4$. Here is the plot, the values in $k\cdot \pi/4$ for $k$ from $0$ to $12$ are plotted as blue points:

Each blue point has to be counted as a jump if there is either left or right near it no red horizontal line.
There are nine such points.

Four of them are isolated at height one. (In $\pi/2$ the situation is very jumpy, we count the point once. The same happens in $5\pi/2$. We do not count these points again.)
Height zero comes with three isolated blue bullets, and one more blue bullet in $2\pi$ (near a red jump), these are further four discontinuities.
We have so far eight points. And there is one more (red jump) blue bullet between $4$ and $6$ at $3\pi/2$, at height minus one.

(All other blue bullets are in silent waters.)
Nine points!

$\sin x$ takes integral values at multiples of $\pi/2$, and $\sin 2x$ takes integral values at multiples of  $\pi/4$. So, first draw the graph of $\left[\sin x\right]$ and $\left[ \sin 2x \right]$. Then, just observe what happens at these points.
Graphs should be easy to draw, there will only be 3 values, these functions will be taking, -1,1 and 0.
Edit: A tip
If you think the process is lengthy, first draw the graph from $0$ to $\pi/4$. Then ahead. Rather than dealing with (0,10) at once.

I check those points, and I'm still unsure as to where the 9th discontinuity is, I could only find 8 points.

As $\theta$ increases, $[\sin \theta]$ only changes value at $\theta = 0$ (where for $-\frac \pi 4 < \theta < 0$ we have $[\sin \theta] = -1$ and for $0\le \theta <\frac \pi 2$ we have $[\sin \theta]= 0$), at $\theta = \frac \pi 2$ (where $[\sin \theta]=1$ but for $w=\theta \pm \epsilon$ we we have $[\sin w] = 0$ for $0 < \epsilon < \frac \pi 2$), and at $\theta = \pi$ we have $[\sin \theta] = 0$ for $\frac \pi 2 < \theta \le \pi$ and $[\sin\theta]=-1$ for $\pi < \theta <\frac {3\pi}2$.  We do not have a change of value at $\theta = \frac {3\pi}2$ as $\pi < \theta < 2\pi$ we have $-1 \le \sin \theta < 0$ so $[\sin \theta] = -1$.
So if we consider then four points:  $x_1=\frac {\pi}4,x_2= \frac {3\pi}4, x_3=\frac {5\pi}4,x_4= \frac {7\pi}4$.  In all $[\sin x]$ is constant and doesn't change value an a small interval.  $x_2$ and $x_4$ we have $[\sin 2x] =-1$ on any small interval so neither are discontinuities.  $x_1$ and $x_2$ we have $[\sin (2x-\epsilon)]\ne [\sin (2x+\epsilon)]$ for small $\epsilon$ so those are discontinuities.  Between $0$ and $10 < (3+\frac 14)\pi$ we have $3$ discontinuities at $x=\frac \pi 4, \frac {5\pi 4}, (2+\frac 14)\pi$.
The other four critical points are $x_5=0, x_6 = \frac \pi 2, x_7=\pi, x_8=\frac {3\pi }4$.
At $x_5 = 0$.  We have for $x < 0$, $[\sin x] + [\sin 2x]=-1+(-1)=-2$ while for $0\le x$ we have $[\sin x]+[\sin 2x]=0+ 0 =0$.  So discontinuity. So $2$ discontinuities at $0$ and $2\pi$.
At $x_6=\frac \pi 2$ we have if $x < \frac \pi 2$ we have $[\sin x] + [\sin 2x] = 0 + 0 =0$. And $x=\frac \pi 2$ we have $1+0 = 1$.  And ant $x > \frac \pi 2$ we have $[\sin x] + [\sin 2x] = 0 + (-1) = -1$.  So $2$ discontinuities a $\frac \pi 2$ and $(2+\frac 12)\pi$.
At $x_7=\pi$ we have if $x < \pi$ then $[\sin x] + [\sin 2x] = 0+(-1)=-1$.  If $x = pi$ then $[\sin x] +[\sin 2x] = 0+0=0$. and if $x>\pi$ we have $[\sin x] + [\sin 2x] = -1 + 0=-1$.  So $2$ dicontinuities at $\pi$ and $3\pi$.
At $x_8=\frac {3\pi}2$ we have $[\sin x]$ is constant, $-1$, while for $2x < 3\pi$ we have $[\sin x] + [\sin 2x] = -1 + 0 = -1$ and for $2x \ge 3\pi$ we have $[\sin x] + [\sin 2x] =-1 + (-1)=-2$ so $1$ discontinuites at $\frac {3\pi}2$.
That's $10$ discontinuities if we count $x =0$.  $9$ if you don't.
